# FB share after login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When popup for access closed, browser blocking new popup for share. It is possible to give the right and open the window share? (without blocked popup)

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js', function(){
  FB.init({
    appId      : '856902511027949',
    status     : true, 
    cookie     : true, 
    xfbml      : true, 
    oauth      : true, 
    version    : 'v2.2'
  });
});

function shareViaFbApp() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    display: 'popup'
  }, function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
} 

$(".init").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      shareViaFbApp();
    } else {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
          shareViaFbApp();
        } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
    }
  });
});
```

I see only one way to get around this problem, create a block like fb popup share after FB.login(), and make share via FB.api().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i find workaround, if you need show share dialog after providing access to your fb app, use **display: 'iframe'** for this.

```
function shareViaFbApp(afterAccess) {
  var display;
  if (afterAccess) {
    display = 'iframe';
  } else {
    display = 'popup';
  }
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    display: display 
  }, function(response){
    console.log(response);
  });
} 

$(".init").on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      shareViaFbApp();
    } else {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.authResponse) {
          shareViaFbApp(true);
        } else {
          console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
      }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `FB.login` in the asynchronous callback of `FB.getLoginStatus`. I know that it´s in an example in the Facebook docs, but it´s wrong and modern browsers block it. Use `FB.getLoginStatus` on page load (to refresh a user session and to check if a user is logged in) and `FB.login` directly on user interaction (mouse click).
You should not use `FB.ui` automatically either, only on direct user interaction like `FB.login`.

Btw, you don´t need to authorize a user for `FB.ui`, it will work without `FB.login` too.

Comment: I need use FB.login for get the responce after share.    

"Response Data available if the user is logged into your app using Facebook and has granted publish_actions. If present, this is the ID of the published Open Graph story." 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: for the share dialog, you don´t even need FB.login. you and publish_actions is not needed either.

Comment: that would get "post_id" need FB.login() .

Comment: yeah, in that case you do need publish_actions and authorization. still, you can´t use FB.login like that, you need a user click for FB.login AND another user click for FB.ui.